# How to get value from material UI Switch component and send it to an API REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a recipe app. I currently have several modals that have material UI switch components for things like course, allergies, diets, cuisine,

How would I go about saving all the values from the Switch components whose states are active once clicked?

I know how to implement the value into my api, just not sure how to store the values of all the clicked switched components.

here is the code I have for the cuisine form

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";

const cuisineStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  form: {
    marginLeft: "20px",
    marginTop: "50px",
  },
  label: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "-40%",
  },
  save: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: "5%",
    bottom: "-90%",
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    color: "white",
    width: "10em",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      color: "grey",
    },
  },

  title: {
    textAlign: "center",
    marginTop: "10px",
    fontSize: "30px",
  },
}));

export default function CuisineForm() {
  const classes = cuisineStyles();
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    american: false,
    italian: false,
    asian: false,
    mexican: false,
    southern: false,
    french: false,
    indian: false,
    chinese: false,
    mediterranean: false,
    greek: false,
    spanish: false,
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.div}>
      <div className={classes.title}>Cuisine</div>

      <FormGroup aria-label="position" row className={classes.form}>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.american}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="american"
            />
          }
          label="American"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.italian}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="italian"
            />
          }
          label="Italian"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.asian}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="asian"
            />
          }
          label="Asian"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.mexican}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="mexican"
            />
          }
          label="Mexican"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.southern}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="southern"
            />
          }
          label="Southern and Soul Food"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.french}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="french"
            />
          }
          label="French"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.indian}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="indian"
            />
          }
          label="Indian"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.chinese}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="chinese"
            />
          }
          label="Chinese"
        />

        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.mediterranean}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="mediterranean"
            />
          }
          label="Mediterranean"
        />

        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.greek}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="greek"
            />
          }
          label="Greek"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.spanish}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="spanish"
            />
          }
          label="Spanish"
        />

        <FormHelperText className={classes.formHelper}>
          Choose one or several cuisines
        </FormHelperText>
      </FormGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You question is a little unclear. In what area are you unsure how to implement the solution? Do you need information on how to create the database, calling the API, or the best way to go about persisting your state with the API?

Comment: I have figured out have the question. I think the api I am using just is not capable of what I want. I used the useContext hook to do what my question asked, but then I was left with the api not searching based on my params. So i need to find a different api.